# JS Files works in HTML but not in laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel

I have given HTML files of a website. When I check all functionality in HTML, everything works fine! However, when I migrate it to the Laravel project, some syntax does not work. In HTML, clicking the edit button, the second field appears and user changes his password. But in the Laravel project, this button does not work. Stylesheets' and scripts' orders are the same. Also, I have not changed anything in the code.

**In HTML file** it looks like this:

[image: HTML File]

However **in Laravel project** it looks like this:

[image: Laravel Project]

Also in console it shows this error:

[image]

[image]

Where can be the problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Post code, markup, error messages, and such **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Answer (score 0):

We should start by fixing the console-error. Sometimes console-errors can stop everything :)

Can you please insert this in line 8:

```
console.log($(".selected-of-dynamic-menu "), $(".selected-of-dynamic-menu ").position());
setTimeout(function(){console.log($(".selected-of-dynamic-menu "), $(".selected-of-dynamic-menu ").position());}, 2000);
```

So we can see whats the problem with the element?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow, please note that the community discourages answering poorly written questions because it encourages OP to keep writing them